# Firefox and Jquery/Javascript form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in firefox, where I'm trying to get a form submission button to display "loading" when a person clicks on it (to prevent multiple submissions of a user clicking it two/three times due to a slow site).

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.submitButton').click(function() {
        document.aform.submit();
        $('.buttonSpan').html('<button class="btn btn-primary disabled">Loading...</button>');

     });
});
```

Chrome executes it correctly, but Firefox *only* changes the HTML in the span surrounding but *doesn't* submit the form. Firefox submits when i click the button *twice*. If I remove the line of the .html() changing, it also submits with no problem.

Here is the form code for reference:

```
<form name="aform" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    ...form data
    <span class="buttonSpan">
         <button class="btn btn-primary submitButton" name="submit"/>Submit</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Does firefox put precedence on html changes and ignore everything else? Again, this works fine in Chrome, but firefox is really killing me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases it is better to use the `submit` event on the form instead of the click event of the submit button. (what if you submit the form by pressing the enter button?)

```
$(function(){
     $('form[name=aform]').submit(function() {
        $('.buttonSpan', this).html('<button class="btn btn-primary disabled">Loading...</button>');

     });
});
```

When using this, you will need to fixed the html of your submit button as I have stated below.

Otherwise I suggest finding the form relative to the submit button:

```
$(function(){
     $('.submitButton').click(function() {
         $(this).closest("form").submit()
        .find('.buttonSpan').html('<button class="btn btn-primary disabled">Loading...</button>');

     });
});
```

Also the *proper* way of defining your submit button is like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: I realize that the "loading" button still allows the form to be submitted multiple times. I can easily change it to a non-button, but any reason why it will still submit the form?

Comment: @Allen, sorry I don't understand your last comment. Which is the "loading" button what do you mean but submitting multiple times?

Comment: @Allen you could get mutliple submit if you use the the 2nd method and change your html to the input. This is because submit is the default action of the input. So you can just skip the `.submit()` in that case.

Comment: ah i see! i suspected as much :)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, but removing a button from the document during its click handler seems likely to cause inconsistent behaviour: does the default action of submitting the form apply to the form that owned it at click-time, or at the post-click-event-time the default action fires (no form)?

Avoid this ambiguity - don't destroy the button by replacing it with new markup. Instead, alter it:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton" name="submit">Submit</button>

$('.submitButton').click(function() {
    $(this).text('Loading...');
    $(this).removeClass('submitButton');
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Note that (a) you don't need to call `form.submit()` because that's the default action for a submit-button anyway; (b) as Munter said, `document.namedElement` is bad form, (c) as d_inevitable said, hooking `form.onsubmit` is almost always a better thing to do than `button.onclick` - though maybe not here if you are specifically only worried about mouse clicks.

Comment: Is it really the default action for `<button>` (not a `<input type="submit">`)?

Comment: It's the default action for `<button type="submit">`. `submit` should be the default `type` for a `<button>`, but it isn't in old versions of IE, so for compatibility we have to use `<button type="submit">` for now.

Comment: Ah okay. +1 for the `.text()`. Didn't see what he was really doing with  that `.html` buttonspan thing. `.text` is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing dom elements by name like you do in `document.aform` is not recommended.

Since you already have the button inside the form you should use the buttons `.form` property.

so something like

```
button.onclick = function () {
    this.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: trying to stay consisten with jquery, but thanks for the help!

Comment: though I realize that the document.form.submit() was javascript --> i would rather change that to a jquery command :)

Comment: There are places like `field.form` where the native DOM is simpler, more readable, more reliable and faster than the jQuery equivalent - there is really no point in shoehorning `$` into every line of code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.submitButton').click(function() {
        $('.buttonSpan').html('<button class="btn btn-primary disabled">Loading...</button>');
        $('form').submit();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example : tested on FF http://jsfiddle.net/JV68U/